# why am i getting Forbidden when i try to use curl in php file

Tags: php, curl

I m trying to integrate a payment method on a website, the first thing I did, I tried a curl code to test it using git console and it works just fine, then I tried to execute the curl command using PHP. I created a file then I used this code:

```
<?php
$endpoint_url = 'https://secure.payinspect.com';
$params = [
  'action'=>'SALE',
  'order_id'=>'ORDER12345',
  'order_amount'=>'1.99',
  'order_currency'=>'USD',
  'order_description'=>'Product',
  'card_number'=>'4111111111111111',
  'card_exp_month'=>'05',
  'card_exp_year'=>'2020',
  'card_cvv2'=>'000',
  'payer_first_name'=>'John',
  'payer_last_name'=>'Doe',
  'payer_address'=>'BigStreet',
  'payer_country'=>'US',
  'payer_state'=>'CA',
  'payer_city'=>'City',
  'payer_zip'=>'123456',
  'payer_email'=>'doe@example',
  'payer_phone'=>'199999999',
  'payer_ip'=>'123.123.123.123',
  'term_url_3ds'=>'http://client.site.com/return.php',
  'recurring_init'=>'N',
  'hash'=>'e3dd86f469f40a5cfedf96a82ff257af'
];
$buff = [];
foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
  array_push($buff, "{$k}={$v}");
}
$url = $endpoint_url . implode('&', $buff);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_close($ch);
    if ($result===false){ print curl_error($curl); }
$response = json_decode($result, true);

echo $result;

?>
```

but I got this error :

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access
```

I googled for this error and I tried to add this line

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

but i still got the same error . 
so what causes this problem and how cauld i fix it

Comment: Forbidden ([HTTP 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)) implies that your script has successfully contacted the server - but they're rejecting it. There could be any number of reasons from an invalid hash to the fact you're using a test card number (according to your code). Aside: what's the point of looping through `$params` and assigning they key/value pairs to `$buff` ? You're just copying the variable, why not just pass `$params` as the POST data in cURL?

Comment: thank you for your fast reply .but it's the fisrt time i use curl and i don't know how to do what you told me at the end . can you tel me how

Comment: thank you very much for your advice, I already remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything else is correct - this *might* fix the problem.

```
<?php
$endpoint_url = 'https://secure.payinspect.com';
$params = [
  'action'=>'SALE',
  'order_id'=>'ORDER12345',
  'order_amount'=>'1.99',
  'order_currency'=>'USD',
  'order_description'=>'Product',
  'card_number'=>'4111111111111111',
  'card_exp_month'=>'05',
  'card_exp_year'=>'2020',
  'card_cvv2'=>'000',
  'payer_first_name'=>'John',
  'payer_last_name'=>'Doe',
  'payer_address'=>'BigStreet',
  'payer_country'=>'US',
  'payer_state'=>'CA',
  'payer_city'=>'City',
  'payer_zip'=>'123456',
  'payer_email'=>'doe@example',
  'payer_phone'=>'199999999',
  'payer_ip'=>'123.123.123.123',
  'term_url_3ds'=>'http://client.site.com/return.php',
  'recurring_init'=>'N',
  'hash'=>'e3dd86f469f40a5cfedf96a82ff257af'
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint_url);

// -- this sets the request method to POST ----
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
// --- end ----

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_close($ch);

if ($result===false) { print curl_error($curl); }
$response = json_decode($result, true);

echo $result;
```

---

I can't say for certain (which means this isn't a *great* answer) but by suffixing the parameters to the URL, in the way you're doing currently, you're creating a **GET** request rather than a **POST** one.

It's quite likely that the receiving service is expecting to see your hash value (and everything else) in the **POST** data - and as it doesn't see it there, it rejects your request completely.

Comment: thank you very much but I already found a solution. I realized that was sending a get request and I changed it like what you said